# Get value from raw query in controller Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My workplace is using raw queries in Laravel for several reasons. Then, I don't know how to get one value from that query.

```
$subgroup = DB::connection('SML')->select('select * from dbSubGroup where KodeSubGrp = :kode', ['kode' => $req->kodesubgroup])
```

The result would show only 1 row. There are column aliasName.
How can I get the value of aliasName?

*** edit ***
$subgroup appears as an Array
I've tried some below but none is working

- $subgroup[0]->aliasName
- $subgroup.aliasName
- $subgroup[0][8]
- $subgroup[0]['aliasName']
- $subgroup['aliasName']

Comment: that `$subgroup` will return a collection right? something like `$subgroup->first()->aliasName` might work. just to be sure `dd($subgroup)` first and see what it contains.

Comment: System said it's an array. I've tried your suggestion but still not working. I've also tried "$subgroup[0]->aliasName", "$subgroup.aliasName", "$subgroup[0][8], & $subgroup[0]['aliasName'] but none was working.

Comment: `dd` the thing to be sure. we cant conjure code from incomplete information, we are programmer not shaman.

Comment: oh, i think you are missing `->get()`.

Comment: dd shows that one is Array.

Comment: ->get() cannot, show this message "Call to a member function get() on array"

Comment: any news on `dd`?

Comment: Using get() ? It's error "Call to a member function get() on array"

Comment: @BagusTesa raw queries are not Query Builder, `select` returns an array of `stdClass` objects

Comment: @TioAjc yeah, kind of forgot that one. just checked on the [API docs](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_select). thats why I need the `dd` to be sure how the array looked like.

Comment: $aliasName = $subgroup[0]->aliasName; OR $aliasName = $subgroup[0]['aliasName'];

Comment: $aliasName = $subgroup[0]->aliasName this is work. thank you pal @KarlHill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the result of the raw query is an array, you can access the value of the `aliasName` column using the array syntax.

```
$aliasName = $subgroup[0]->aliasName;
```

Comment: Yeah. I've tried this one before but not working. Actualy i've tried this before. I think i've do mistyping. Maybe. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @TioAjc if your query returns nothing it will get an error though.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the query, buddy. As you suggest before about using dd, the array already right.